# Why exporting map with qgis2web to Leaflet ends with errors?

Tags: qgis, leaflet, qgis2web

Exporting qgis2web map with OpenLayers completes with no error.. but with Leaflet it ends with following errors..

```
An error has occurred while executing Python code: 

IndexError: 1 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.var/app/org.qgis.qgis/data/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/maindialog.py", line 350, in saveMap
    feedback=self.feedback)
  File "/home/user/.var/app/org.qgis.qgis/data/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/leafletWriter.py", line 101, in write
    folder=dest_folder)
  File "/home/user/.var/app/org.qgis.qgis/data/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/leafletWriter.py", line 272, in writeLeaflet
    useVT, useShapes, useOSMB)
  File "/home/user/.var/app/org.qgis.qgis/data/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/leafletLayerScripts.py", line 127, in writeVectorLayer
    useShapes, feedback)
  File "/home/user/.var/app/org.qgis.qgis/data/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/leafletStyleScripts.py", line 65, in getLayerStyle
    sl, useMapUnits, feedback)
  File "/home/user/.var/app/org.qgis.qgis/data/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/leafletStyleScripts.py", line 180, in getSymbolAsStyle
    sl = symbol.symbolLayer(sl)
IndexError: 1


Python version: 3.7.3 (default, Nov 10 2011, 15:00:00) [GCC 8.3.0] 
QGIS version: 3.10.3-A Coruña A Coruña, 0e1f8464 

Python Path:
/app/share/qgis/python
/home/user/.var/app/org.qgis.qgis/data/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
/home/user/.var/app/org.qgis.qgis/data/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins
/app/share/qgis/python/plugins
/usr/lib/python37.zip
/usr/lib/python3.7
/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload
/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages
/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages
/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy-1.14.3-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg
/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MarkupSafe-1.0-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg
/home/user/.var/app/org.qgis.qgis/data/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
/home/user/.var/app/org.qgis.qgis/data/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web
/home/user/.var/app/org.qgis.qgis/data/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins
/home/user/Documents/Web Map
```

Why it is happening??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this be because you are using a categorized/graduated/rule-based renderer, and different symbols within the renderer have different numbers of symbol layers? This is an existing limitation/bug in Leaflet exports:

https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/828